# grep single line from multiline string

Tags: ruby, grep

A variable `str` holds a multi line string. I want to grep a line from it. I want to grep the string line `kernel release                721` and assign it to a variable. Is there any way to do so?

```
irb(main):152:0> print str
*************************** Component ********************
c:\temp\agent\bin\CAR.exe: 721, patch 618, changelist 1633822, NTAMD64, opt
**********************************************************
--------------------
AGENT information
--------------------

kernel release                721

kernel make variant           721_REL

compiled on                   NT 6.1 7601 S x86 MS VC++ 14.00 for NTAMD64

compiled for                  64 BIT

compilation mode              Non-Unicode

compile time                  Mar 21 2016 21:07:50

patch number                  12

latest change number          1659167


---------------------
supported environment
---------------------

operating system
Windows NT 5.0
Windows NT 5.1
Windows NT 5.2
Windows NT 6.0
Windows NT 6.1
```

Comment: Why do you require that `grep` be used? Consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.lines.grep /pattern/
```

or

```
string.each_line.grep /pattern/
```

which might be more efficient

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you are interested in the value, i.e. `721`:

```
kernel_release = str[/^kernel release\s+(\w+)$/, 1]
#=> "721"
```

The regular expression matches a line that starts with `kernel release`, followed by whitespace and ends with one or more word characters. The latter are captured and the second argument `1` refers to that capture group.