# Ruby convert string array to string

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a ruby string array value and i want to get it as string value. I am using ruby with chef recipe. Running in windows platform. Code-

```
version_string = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('some.exe -version').run_command     
Log.info(version.stdout.to_s)    
extract_var = version_string.stdout.to_s.lines.grep(/ver/)
Log.info('version:'+ extract_var.to_s)
```

output is coming-

```
version           530    
[2016-06-08T07:03:49+00:00] INFO:  version ["version                530\r\n"]
```

I want to extract 530 string only.

Comment: You want string value or integer??

Comment: Hi @llya I have updated complete code. Please look into it.

Comment: Did you see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37610826/477037) to your last question?

Comment: @Stefan I immediately downvoted the question and have my answer removed.

Comment: You initially had a simple question that was ambiguous. You said "I want to get only string value as- `val=720` only". If you had written `val="720"`, that would be consistent, but you wrote `val=720`, `720` being an integer, not a string. @Ilya simply wanted to know if the value of `val` was a string or an integer. You did not answer that question, but instead added a mountain of irrelevant `chef`-related bumph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep single line from multiline string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610572/grep-single-line-from-multiline-string)

Comment: @Stefan I already tried your suggestion but it was not filtering as a **string**.

Comment: I have been ban to ask any more questions. @mudasobwa Can you please let me know the reason for down voting so that I can improve.

Comment: @BiswajitDas You’ve asked a question, received the correct well-explained answer from the ruby professional and made no effort to read/understand it. Instead you posted the same question once again, in hope that we have nothing to do here, besides providing you the answers that won’t require any effort from you besides copy-paste.

Comment: @mudasobwa well. This is not completely duplicate with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610572/grep-single-line-from-multiline-string) but for **different purpose**. Possibly you can very clearly see only one I marked as answer for both the questions. One **mistake** I have done here I have used the same example for both the questions. If I have a very good ruby professionals I would have not asked these kind of questions here.You can not simply assume since I am the question owners for both the questions. I strictly need a strong explanation from you people.

Comment: Updated code. hopefully duplicate mark can be removed from this post and get upvote for this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want `val = 720` and not `val = "720"` you can write

```
val = strvar.first.to_i
  #=> 720
```

Comment: Hi @cary-swoveland I have updated the question in detail. please look into it.

Answer (score 3):

long time no see since Rot :)

You can use some Chef helper methods and regular expressions to make this a little easier.

```
output = shell_out!('saphostexec.exe -version', cwd: 'C:\\Program Files\\hostctrl\\exe').stdout
if output =~ /kernel release\s+(\d+)/
  kernel_version = $1
else
  raise "unable to parse kernel version"
end
Chef::Log.info(kernel_version)
```

Comment: yeah. Somehow shell_out was not working in windows system. not sure if I need to include any library.

Comment: It depends on your version of Chef, you can use `include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut` but this is already done for you in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the first series of digits found as an integer from the `current_kernel` string with [String#[regexp]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) :

```
current_kernel[/\d+/].to_i
  #=> 720
```